# Meteor angular update to 1.3.4.4 (from 1.3.4.1) broke templates

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

After running `meteor update` today in my meteor-angular project (working version is 1.3.4.1) nothing loads anymore, and multiple errors appear in the console, such as:

```
angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:13439 
    Error: [angular-meteor][err][404] client/templates/base.html - HTML template does not exists! You can disable this error by following this guide http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.11/templates
    at Object.$provide.decorator.$delegate.get (templates-handler.js:33)
    at sendReq (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:11408)
    at serverRequest (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:11148)
    at processQueue (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:15772)
    at angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:15788
    at Scope.$eval (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:17040)
    at Scope.$digest (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:16856)
    at Scope.$apply (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:17148)
    at bootstrapApply (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:1728)
    at Object.invoke (angular_angular.js?hash=08f63d2…:4640)
```

(one error for each template).

It's important to note that everything worked perfectly prior to the upgrade.

The code which loads the template:

```
$stateProvider.state('base', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'client/templates/base.html',
        controller: 'BaseCtrl as base',
        ...
```

Ideas?

### == Edit 2016.7.27 ==

Whatever the problem was, it's now fixed. Today I run:

```
meteor update --release 1.3.5.1
```

meteor updated, and everything still works like a charm!

## Note: this problem still happens when updating to meteor 1.4

Answer (score 3):

Use the following style

```
import templateUrl from './meteorSample.html'

angular.module(module.name)
  .component('meteorSample', {
   templateUrl
 })
```

Comment: I think this is using angular2, right? Any solution using angular1?

Answer (score 0):

Archimedes Trajano's comment is almost right, however the complete working code to the question should be something like the following:

```
import templateUrl from './base.html';

$stateProvider.state('base', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl,
        controller: 'BaseCtrl as base',
        ...
```

Comment: I put import templateUrl from './client/global/template/login.html'; but I receive this server error Unable to resolve some modules:

  "../client/global/template/login.html" in /C/Users/mg-ya/Documents/worker_platform/lib/app.js
(os.windows.x86_32)

Comment: remove all path and just leave ./ as the current path, assuming your html file is placed in the same directory as your js file.

So that, the final import looks like this:

import templateUrl from "./login.html";

Comment: note that these hacks no longer seem necessary as `meteor update --release 1.3.5.1` fixed the issue